# How can I uninstall mir?

Tags: unity, 13.10, mir

I followed the instructions here to install Mir on my laptop on Saucy 13.10.
[Ubuntu Mir](http://unity.ubuntu.com/mir/)

It works well except for a known bug which causes the Laptop to go into low graphics after suspend.

So for a while I would like to go back to default without Mir. Ubsure how I can exactly get this done. What packages do I need to install to get back to default?

Comment: Have you done `sudo apt-get purge mir-demos unity-system-compositor`? Those are the packages you installed so removing them should fix the problem.

Comment: It also installed.libboost-program-options-dev libboost-program-options1.53-dev
  libboost-program-options1.53.0 libboost1.53-dev libgflags2 libglm-dev
  libgoogle-glog0 libmirclient-dev libmirclient3 libmirplatform
  libmirprotobuf-dev libmirprotobuf0 libmirserver-dev libmirserver7
  libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-lite7 libunwind8 mir-doc mircommon-dev
  xserver-xorg-xmir zlib1g-dev

Comment: Which I can apt-get autoremove. Lets see if system works after removing Mir.

Comment: Well its running after reboot and there is no unity-system-compositor listed so it must be on X. sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~$ ps ax | grep "unity"
 1487 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/lib/unity/unity-panel-service
 1917 ?        Sl     0:00 /usr/lib/libunity-webapps/unity-webapps-service
 2163 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep unity

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to remove Mir with the following:

```
sudo apt-get purge mir-demos unity-system-compositor
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To remove any leftover dependencies. Reboot the machine.

To check if Mir was successfully removed run:

```
ps afx | grep unity-system-compositor
```

There should be no process with a name of `unity-system-compositor`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the session

```
sudo apt-get remove unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

Now remove the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```